# Appending into an array from completion block

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I am attempting to append the results of the parse query into usersData

```
struct Data {
    var FirstName:String!
    var LastName:String!
    var Gender:String!
    var Age:String!
}
```

In the class I have

```
var usersData = [Data]()
```

I am using this to

```
func parseUsersData(completionHandler: [Data] -> Void) {
    var usersDataArray = [Data]()
    let query = PFQuery(className: "_User")
    query.fromLocalDatastore()
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            if let user = objects as? [PFObject]! {
                for object in user! {

                    var singleData = Data()

                    singleData.FirstName = object["firstName"] as! String
                    singleData.LastName = object["lastName"] as! String
                    singleData.Gender = object["gender"] as! String
                    singleData.Age = object["age"] as! String

                    usersDataArray.append(singleData)
                }
            }
            completionHandler(usersDataArray)
        }

    }
}
```

finally, I am trying to do this:

Edit: To clarify, I need to pass the data from the queries, userDataArray, into the array usersData.

```
    parseUsersData { (usersDataArray) -> Void in
        usersData.append(usersDataArray)
    }
```

The error I am getting is

```
  Cannot convert value of type '[Data]' to expected argument type 'Data'
```

Comment: You can try `usersData += usersDataArray` anyhow append takes an array element and appends it to an array of those elements.

Answer (score 0):

In your last code block you seem to appending a Data array to a Data object `usersData.append(usersDataArray)` which causes error I think. Did you mean to write `usersDataArray.append(usersData)` which makes a lot more sense?

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to add an array of Data to an array that is looking for Data Objects.  Add a new struct that handles your Data Array and then change the usersData to look for DataArray's:

```
struct DataArray {
    var array = [Data]()
}
```

And change the line:

```
var usersData = [DataArray]()
```

Comment: This is giving me the same error. Could you expand on this ?

Comment: Just to clarify you do want an array of arrays right?  What line are you getting the error at? Also how do you declare usersData?

Comment: Im sorry, I am not sure if that is what I am looking for.. Does that sound right? I am trying to get the data from usersDataArray into usersData. Right now I am declaring usersData as var usersData: Data! .

Comment: Thats probably your problem then.  usersData needs to be an array.  Declare it as ```var usersData = [Data]()``` .  Then do ```usersData. appendContentsOf(usersDataArray)```

Comment: I apologize, I did have it like that. I thought you were referring to something else

Comment: Would you mind posting more code?  Its difficult to help with missing information.

Answer (score 0):

`usersDataArray` is an array. To add an array to an other array, prefer `appendContentsOf` :

```
usersData.appendContentsOf(usersDataArray)
```

Comment: When I print out UsersData I am getting an empty array

Comment: Where do you print usersData ? Is usersDataArray not empty ?

Comment: I am printing out userData in viewDidLoad. UsersDataArray is filled with data from the parse query.

Comment: Can you post screenshots of prints of usersData and usersDataArray ?

Comment: http://imgur.com/mvJdBwm prints out from usersData.appendContentsOf(usersDataArray)

Comment: I don't know where you print these values. Look at this screenshot : http://puu.sh/lJHfC/bb973545cb.png. I have something in usersData.

Comment: @bobdawg I think your problem is an asynchronous one : http://puu.sh/lJHGa/6e0684d7d9.png. As you can see on my screenshot, first, usersData is empty because the web service call is not finished. Second, when the webservice call is finished, usersData is not empty.

Comment: I am printing outside of the closure

Comment: I am getting the same results as you are, I put the print statement inside of the closure and I am getting the results I want. Except, when I move the print statement outside of the closure I am getting nil

Comment: I have explained your problem on my last comment :)

Comment: If you have some tasks to do with usersData, add it inside closure because outside it's not possible... or create a function called inside this closure.

Comment: Thanks @mickacapi. I appreciate the help.. , what you are saying is that there is no way to get the data out  of the closure?

Comment: Just a thought, could I use the closure ro return a data object?